# file extension with .o in cmake

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I am working on a C project. I am using cmake as build generator.
I have set the below things in my cmakelists.txt just below project() command

```
set(CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE 1)
set(CMAKE_ASM_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE 1)
set(CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION .o)
set(CMAKE_ASM_OUTPUT_EXTENSION .o)
```

I have files with .c extensions and assembly files with .s extensions.
During compilation, i see that files are created with .obj extension(file.c --> file.obj)
my expectation is with .o extension(file.c --> file.o).
anything i have to set apart from the above commands ?

Comment: `.obj` if often used in Windows while `.o` is often used in Posix. I would use the default extensions instead of setting them explicitly.

Comment: i am building software for embedded system(cross compiling). i have some pre defined object files with .o extension. it could be helpful if  other files are also generated with .o extension

Comment: I see. Have you set [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html#variable:CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME)? I would expect all files to get the proper extensions by default when using CMake, but I could be wrong.

Comment: yes.. i have set..  #Specify the environment -- embedded
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "Generic")

#Specifiy the Architecture -- PowerPC
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "ppc")

Comment: What if you specify the actual OS name instead of `Generic`?

Comment: The os used here is "tresos". If i use this, i am getting error "system is unknown to cmake"

Comment: I see. Perhaps you could ask Elektrobit for advice. They probably have some ideas how to set it up properly.

Comment: i am getting expected result by setting set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "Linux") and executable also getting generated. will it be a problem ?

Comment: If the rest of the cross compiling options are ok it could work. You could try `Posix` too. The EB tresos OS:es seems to be based on `Posix` (just like Linux).

Comment: ok.. thank you @TedLyngmo